# Is it legal C to declare a non-const variable 'const' externally?

Tags: c, linker, constants

Say I have a file, window.h, which defines:

```
extern const int window_width, window_height;
```

I don't want anyone to change these variables, so they're const for all includers of window.h. However, is it legal to declare them non-const in the source file?

```
// window.c
int window_width, window_height;

void onResizeWindow(int w, int h) {
    window_width = w;
    window_height = h;
}
```

This compiles without linker errors for me in Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.22.7). But is it legal and well-defined C?

Comment: I'm not posting an answer because I'm not certain what the standard says, but I would think not. The compiler might assume these variables do not get modified after initialization while in reality they can be modified.

Comment: as an aside, it's probably better to just write `int getWindowWidth()` and `int getWindowHeight()` functions rather than exposing the "const" variables at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is undefined behaviour. Two declarations for the same object must have compatible types, and a non-`const`-qualified type is not compatible with the `const`-qualified version of the same type. (Like other issues which involve two or more translation units, this undefined behaviour does not require a diagnostic. But the absence of a diagnostic message doesn't mean that it's OK. It just means that the compiler only looks at one translation unit at a time, so it can't see inconsistencies.)

It is not an error to use a pointer to a `const`-qualified type to access a non-`const` object of that type, or even to use a pointer to a non-`const` qualified type to read from (but not mutate) a `const`-qualified object. But be aware that as long as the actual definition of the variable is not `const`-qualified, it is also not an error to "cast away `const`" from a pointer and use it to modify the variable.