# Declaring as const, but defining as non-const, C

Tags: c

Is it valid to declare in my headers a const variable, but define it as a non-const variable for internal use?

Comment: Just asking ;) why would you do that ?

Comment: Have you tried it to see what happens?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it legal C to declare a non-const variable 'const' externally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63525933/is-it-legal-c-to-declare-a-non-const-variable-const-externally)

Comment: @NateEldredge yes, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only logical way of declaring variables in the header file is to declare them as `extern`

As `#include` only inserts the text of the header file into the source code file (https://godbolt.org/z/nor8nz) you can simply test you idea in the single source file:

```
extern const int x;

int x;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PWEzGM

You will get the error:

```
1
ARM gcc 8.2
- 347ms

<source>:4:5: error: conflicting type qualifiers for 'x'
 int x;
     ^
<source>:2:18: note: previous declaration of 'x' was here
 extern const int x;
                  ^
Compiler returned: 1
```

Answer (score 3):

No, this causes undefined behavior.

C17 6.6.7 (2):

> All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type; otherwise, the
> behavior is undefined.

6.7.3 (11):

> For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the identically qualified version of a
> compatible type; the order of type qualifiers within a list of specifiers or qualifiers does not affect the
> specified type.

Since `const` is a qualifier, types such as `int` and `const int` are not compatible, and therefore it is undefined behavior to have both an `int` and a `const int` declaration of the same object.  (And the definition of the object is itself a declaration, so it counts.)

One of many possible undesired consequences, in practice, could be that in source files (translation units) that have a `const` declaration, the compiler may assume that the variable is actually constant, and may fail to notice if it is modified.  For example, code like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern const int x;
void bar(void);
void foo(void) {
    printf("%d\n", x);
    bar();
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

may cache the value of `x` in a callee-saved register across the call to `bar()`, and so will always print the same value twice.  [See on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/x48Ex6).  This would happen even if another file contains

```
int x = 5;
void bar(void) {
    x = 6;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope for better answers that can address the direct question about the validity.

But this is almost certainly a bad approach. My suggestion is to use a function that returns the value instead. Another option would be to use a pointer to const. Something like:

```
int x;
int *const ptr = &x;
```

Using globals the way you describe is dangerous territory. If I ever would like to do something like that, I'd probably just accept that I have to be really careful.

One might be tempted to use a pointer like this:

```
const int x;
int *ptr = &x; // Bad, bad idea
```

But do NOT try to do that, as it invokes undefined behavior. Source: [Can we change the value of an object defined with const through pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3801557/6699433)